# Transform `Request` headers to plain key value object

Tags: javascript, iterator, javascript-objects

I am trying to convert a list of headers from a Request (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/headers) object to a plain key/value object.

```js
// Create a Request object.
const req = new Request('https://example.com', {
    headers: {
        'X-Test-header': 'Test'
    }
});
```

Sadly, the following doesn't work because the `headers` property is an `iterator`:

Unusable result:

```js
const result1 = JSON.stringify(req.headers);
// result1 =  `{}`
```

Usable result but very verbose to create:

```js
const headers = {};
for(const [key, value] of req.headers.entries()) {
    headers[key] = value;
}
const result2 = JSON.stringify(headers)
// result2 = `{'X-Test-Header': 'Test'}`
```

I'm looking for some sort of a one liner (maybe including `Array.from()` or [some of the other methods on the `Request.headers` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/entries) like `.keys()`/`.values()` so that I am able to stringify the result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) method, and then stringify that object like below. The `.fromEntries()` method will invoke the iterator of your headers object (ie: the [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/entries)) to grab the entries of the header object, and then use that to create an object. You can then pass this to `JSON.stringify()` to get your JSON string:

```js
const req = new Request('https://example.com', {
    headers: {
        'X-Test-header': 'Test'
    }
});

const result1 = JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(req.headers));
console.log(result1);
```

Comment: @Flame this is the more accurate answer.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed how's that so, both give the same solution but yours also gives the `Array.from` option for another result. I cant decide now. Both answers came within minutes

Comment: @Flame I guess Sajeeb's code is still accurate, but it does call some extra methods that can be skipped in this case. `Object.fromEntries()` is typically called with an array, but it also accepts an iterator, so converting it to an array first using `Array.from()` can be skipped.

Comment: If you console the `req.headers` then inside this you can see there is an `.entries()` method of this. And `Object.fromEntries()` from it's name it says it accpets `entries` and headers also gives you entries. So, you no need to create an array explicitly.

Comment: alrighty; thx both for making my code a little better

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to grab the headers as a regular object then you could generate an 2d array with key-value pair using `Array.from()` and create an object from the 2d array using `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const req = new Request('https://example.com', {
    headers: {
      'X-Test-header': 'Test',
      'accepts': 'application/json'
    }
});

const headers = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(req.headers.entries()));


console.log(JSON.stringify(headers));
```

Why this is working? The `req.headers.entries()` provides you an `Interator {}` which is an array type but not array. So, you could not implement any `Array.prototype` methods on it. But fortunately, `Array.from()` accepts any array type and converts it into an array.

So, `Array.from(req.headers.entries())` generates an 2D array like -

```js
[['X-Test-header', 'Test'], ['accepts', 'application/json']]
```

And if you see the `Object.fromEntries()` structure, then you find that this method takes the same 2D type array for generating an object.

Now you could apply `JSON.stringify()` on the headers object.